# ViewPager Fragment occasionally wont inflate/load

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, android-studio, android-fragments

I've searched in many places and tried many solutions to the following problem, I hope you can help!

I've made a Tabbed Activity with 6 fragments, and a logging screen from a blank activity. The Tabbed activity is the main activity which has a ViewPager container to show the actual tab, however the logging activity is the first one to load and show. Somewhere along the process (very far into it actually) I've noticed that the fragments inside the container will occasionally wont show. They would sometimes reappear when I rotate the screen, or when I use the Logout feature from the menu and then login back in (sometimes takes several tries until is shows back up).
I've read through but could't figure it out. 
I've tried changing the

> (getChildFragmentManager(), getResources()));

but I think I don't place it in the right spot.

**My MainActivty**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private boolean verified;
public static String token;

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
 * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
 * may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        verified = extras.getBoolean("verify");
        token = extras.getString("token");
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login Successful", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if(verified != true) {
            logoutSuccessful();
    }


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the 
three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new 
SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        //mSectionsPagerAdapter.saveState();

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
        //getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.logo_small);
        //set icons for tabs
        for (int i = 0; i < tabLayout.getTabCount(); i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_scan);
            } else {
                if (i == 1) {

tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.icon_pricecheck);
                } else {
                    tabLayout.getTabAt(i).setIcon(R.drawable.logo_small);
                }
            }
        }



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    if (id == R.id.action_logout) {
        logoutSuccessful();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
 //DELETED PLACEHOLDER CLASS

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class 
below).
      //  return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        switch (position){
            case 0: Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
                return tab1;
            case 1: Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
                return tab2;
            case 2: Tab3 tab3 = new Tab3();
                return tab3;
            case 3: Tab4 tab4 = new Tab4();
                return tab4;
            case 4: Tab5 tab5 = new Tab5();
                return tab5;
            case 5: Tab6 tab6 = new Tab6();
                return tab6;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show total pages.
        return 6;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "SCAN";
            case 1:
                return "PRICE CHECK";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
            case 3:
                return "SECTION 4";
            case 4:
                return "SECTION 5";
            case 5:
                return "SECTION 6";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
private void logoutSuccessful(){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
    MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
    finish();
}
}
```

**Tab1:**

```
public class Tab1 extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
Button btnUpc;
EditText txtUPC;
Vector<UPCProductObject> v = new Vector<>();
Editable value;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup 
container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1, container,false);
    lblUpcResult = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lblUPCResult);
    txtUPC = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUPC);
    btnUpc = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUPC);
    btnUpc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //hide keyboard
            InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) 
getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(txtUPC.getWindowToken(), 0);
            btnUpc.setEnabled(false);
            value = txtUPC.getText();
          new searchUPC().execute();
        }});
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new Tab1(), "Scan")
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**activity_main xml**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.dabush.shen.mcrpos.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="90dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:src="@drawable/logo_small"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                />
        </FrameLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:minHeight="80dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
        app:tabTextColor="#FFD5D2D2" />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<!--FLOATING EDITABLE BUTTON
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/fab"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
     android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
     app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
     -->
```

**tab1 xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/tblSearch"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/tblSearch" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/tab1_title"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:text="@string/scan_desc"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/tblSearch"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtUPC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnUPC"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="SEARCH" />

    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</TableLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblUPCResult"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tblSearch"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="91dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="12sp" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listUpc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="375dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tblSearch"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:textAlignment="center" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction() in ur 1st fragment. And in activity lifecycle, onRotate, activity was destroyed and recreate, you need to save it on saveInstance and reload UI onRestoreInstance

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking how to implement that but all I got was how to save certain variable states inside the fragment and not how to restore its entire view (that's what I need since its disappearing, right?)